# looping through the value of this.state using .map() error ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Complete beginner to reactJS. I am trying to loop through the values of `this.state` and I am having issue.

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { stats: [] };  
  } 

  //assume this part has no issue
  // I added it just to make my work more understandable
 axios.get(this.props.source)
    .then((result) => {
    this.setState({
        stats: result 
      });

    });
```

//here is where the issue arise

```
  render(){
    return(
      {this.state.stats.map(function(val,res){
            console.log(val)
      })})
}
```

The error I am getting is `TypeError: this.state.stats.map is not a function`.

Comment: Check if the value of `result` is an array itself. try console.logging `result`. the error usually occurs when `this.state.stats` is not an array

Comment: `{this.state.stats && this.state.stats.map(…)}`

Comment: @illiteratewriter the value of result is json. like [{'name':'value','id':'number'},{'name':'value','id':'number'}]

Comment: @Li357 i dont think I got that

Comment: Please create a reproducible example. All these random bits and bobs where you say "assume this part has no issue" could contain issues. As it is, simply having a constructor and a render function as you have does not result in the error message you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that stats is not array as you think. For validation, I would suggest to add `Array.isArray(this.state.stats)` before using it. I would also suggest to break with debugger on initialisation of this variable to ensure that it will stay as an array.

Comment: Probably because `result` is a JSON string or similar?

Comment: any suggestion how to loop through JSON

Comment: Copy ajax result for more suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing some important things here. It's a good idea to put your async request into `ComponentDidMount` method.

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you
>   need to load data from a remote endpoint, **this is a good place to
>   instantiate the network request**.

Also, it's a good idea to check if your stats variable exists before go through it.

Here is a full example:

```js
class CustomComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { 
      stats: [] 
    };  
  } 

  componentDidMount () {
    this.setState({stats: [1,2,3,4]})
  }

  render () {
    const { stats } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        {stats && stats.map((val,res) => {
          console.log(val)
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <CustomComponent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

More info about componentdidmount:  https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: I have included ComponentDidMount() on my original code. the axios section has nothing to do with the issue. Thanks for the suggestion anyways

Comment: Ok..so my guess is you are doing something wrong in the render method. I updated my answer with a code snippet.